# Scanning a file containing two different variables into linked list using c. Why isn't my code working. It is stopping while running

Tags: c, file, struct

NOTE: This is only a part of my program.

The intention of the code here is to read contents of a file that contains some employees name and id's into a linked list. It then should add the new employee(s) information entered through keyboard into file using linked list only.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
//------------------------------------------------
FILE *fp  
struct node
{
    char name[50];
    int id;
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL,*temp,*ptr,*new,*curr;
//------------------------------------------------------

void insert()
{
    char filename[20],empname[50];
    int empid,looprun,i,x,n;
    printf("\nEnter the branch name in which you wish to insert the new employee(s) data: ");   
    scanf("%s",filename);
    fp=fopen(filename,"r+");
    printf("\nEnter how many new employees you wish to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fseek(fp,0L,2); /*To reach end of the file*/
    x=ftell(fp);    //Noting end position of a file
    rewind(fp);
    start=NULL;
    while(ftell(fp)<x) //to scan all the contents of the file in linked list
    {
        if(looprun==0)
       {
            new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            start=new;
            curr=new;  
            fscanf(fp,"%s%d",new->name,&new->id);
            looprun++;             
       }
       else
       {
    new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    curr->next=new;
    new->next=NULL;
    fscanf(fp,"%s%d",new->name,&new->id);
    curr=new;
    looprun++;
       }
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    printf("Enter employee %d name and id: ",i+1);
    new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    scanf("%s%d",new->name,&new->id);
    curr->next=new;
    new->next=NULL;
    curr=new;
   }
        printf("\nEmployees information succesfully inserted!!\n");


}
```

Sample of a file that is to be read:

```
sailesh 160031158  
mani 160052426  
pavan 160058914
```

ERROR: The code compiles perfectly without showing any error. During run time, it works upto taking input of number of employee info to be added. After that , as soon as I entered employee 1 details, it stops working and a pop up window says that miniproject.c has stopped working.

Comment: Provide the file to be read also..also provide what error comes and when it stops (sample output)

Comment: done sir- @minigeek

Comment: What solution should i put? I didn't get you @minigeek

Comment: oh sorry i thought you solved problem lol !

Comment: you can check additional warnings using `cc -Wall codename.c`

Comment: try putting `fflush(stdin)` after every scanf

Comment: @minigeek: "*`fflush(stdin)`*" doing so might very well provoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour: http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html

Comment: @alk oh thanx for info :)..it is dangerous then hmm